# Create Users in ASP.net website administration tool

Tags: asp.net-membership

I am exploring the Membership class of the ASP.net and configuring the roles and users.

Is it a must to set security question in ASP.net administration tool? Because I don't think my system needs the security question.

If I have quite a number of users, how can I import the list of users? I don't want to create users in the administation tool one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the requirements in the web.config file.

```
<membership defaultProvider="myProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
        <providers>
            <add 
                name="myProvider" 
                type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
                connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" 
                enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
                enablePasswordReset="true" 
                requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
                applicationName="/" 
                requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
                passwordFormat="Hashed" 
                maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
                minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
                minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
                passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
                passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

**requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"** is the important bit for your example.

The membership provider API enables you to create users in code. eg Membership.CreateUser
You easily use this to write a small utility to import your users from a list.

Answer (score 1):

you can code a method which loops the users that you want to import and import them one by one with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8yy6w3h.aspx

you will get a membershipuser object from that method which you can configure further